# Determine constant of tangent plane to surface (ellipsodal sphere)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In a given problem, the goal is to find a tangent plane of an equation $x² + 2y² +3z² = 6$ that also includes some points $(6,0,0)$ and $(0,3,0)$. The points should not be relevant for the question I'm asking however.

The answer to the problem is a plane $x + 2y + 3z = 6$, but is this equation really a tangent to the plane? If we for example set $y=0$ and $z=0$, then $x=\sqrt{6}$ in the original equation but $x=6$ in the plane equation and thus cannot include the same tangent point. Doesn't that mean that the plane is not a tangent plane to the surface, or doesn't a tangent plane need to include the point that it is tangent to?

I'm comparing this to having a sphere $x² + y² + z² = r$ that would have a tangent plane with $x = \sqrt{r}$ if $y=0$ and $z=0$ and from that reasoning I derive that the radius can't simply be $r$ for a plane. Even though I understand that I am missing something in my reasoning.

Comment: Isn't (1, 1, 1) the tangent point from setting the ellipsoid sphere equation equal to the tangent plane equation?

Comment: Note that there are two solutions to the original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plane is really a tangent to the ellipsoid. The point you're missing is $(1,1,1)$, which is the tangential point between the surface and the plane. See $1+2+3=6=1^2+2(1)^2+3(1)^2$. Check also $(6,0,0)$ and $(0,3,0)$ lie on the plane.

If you set $y=0,z=0$ in the equation of the plane, you'll end up with some other points on the plane. If you plug a point into the equation of the ellipsoid, it gives you the information whether the point is inside the ellipsoid or not. From you example, you set $y=0,z=0$, the ellipsoid gives you $x=\sqrt{6}$ because there's a point $(\sqrt{6},0,0)$ on the surface, but not on the plane. $(6,0,0)$ is on the plane but not the surface. This has no implication whether the plane is not a tangent plane and so on. The only moment you have two equations equal to each other, is at the point $(1,1,1)$.

Comment: Wow it is so confusing with multiple variables, but yeah... this makes sense. Had to think again about why two equations equal to eachother means that it is an intersection, even with multiple variables.